# Tengo un problema cuando voy a insertar una imagen en phpMyAdmin de Hostinger

Tags: java, phpmyadmin, hosting

Mi aplicación esta desarrollada en Java.

Tengo un problema cuando voy a insertar(o guardar) una imagen en mi Base Datos que esta en  phpMyAdmin de Hostinger.

Cuando hago la inserción(o guardo) de un registro sin imagen se guarda perfectamente pero al momento de hacerlo con imagen me sale el siguiente error:

**com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions. CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 22,643 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 22,824 milliseconds ago. is longer than server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configures values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=True' to avoid this problem**

En otro hosting no me pasa este error y uso el mismo método de guardar.

Este es el código de guardar los datos:

```
public static void GuardarPaciente(String ruta){
        PreparedStatement ps;
        ResultSet rs;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        
        
        Date date = Pacientes.FechaNacimiento.getDate();
        long d = date.getTime();
        java.sql.Date fecha = new java.sql.Date(d);

        int seguroid = PacienteCRUD.obtenerSeguroid();
   
        try{
            File file = new File(ruta);
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            
////            Conexion con = new Conexion();
////            Connection conexion = con.getConection();
                    Connection c = ConexionS.getConnection();
            ps = c.prepareStatement("insert into paciente (nombres,apellidos,seguroid,direccion,fecha_nac,fecha_creacion,otrosDatos,poliza,telefono,celular,"
                    + "cedula,correo,trabajo_telefono,trabajo_nombre,trabajo_extension,estadoCivil,sexo,imagen,nss) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, Pacientes.nombres.getText());
            ps.setString(2,Pacientes.apellidos.getText());
            ps.setInt(3,seguroid);
            ps.setString(4,Pacientes.direccion.getText());
            ps.setDate(5, (fecha));
            ps.setString(6,Pacientes.fechaCreacion.getText());
            ps.setString(7, Pacientes.otrosDatos.getText());
            ps.setString(8, Pacientes.poliza.getText());
            ps.setString(9, Pacientes.telefono.getText());
            ps.setString(10, Pacientes.celular.getText());
            ps.setString(11, Pacientes.cedula.getText());
            ps.setString(12,Pacientes.correo.getText());
            ps.setString(13, Pacientes.telefonoTrabajo.getText());
            ps.setString(14, Pacientes.lugarTrabajo.getText());
            ps.setString(15, Pacientes.extension.getText());
            ps.setString(16, Pacientes.CB_EstadoCivil.getSelectedItem().toString());
            ps.setString(17, Pacientes.CB_Sexo.getSelectedItem().toString());
            ps.setBinaryStream(18,fis,(int)file.length());
            ps.setString(19, Pacientes.nss.getText());
            
            int resultado = ps.executeUpdate(); // Ejecutamos la insercion de los datos
            
            if (resultado >0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro insertado correctamente");
                    if(Pacientes.nuevoPaciente == 1){
                        Pacientes.botonSalir.doClick();
                        HistoriaClinicaCRUD.SeleccionarPaciente(Pacientes.pacienteid.getText()); 
                        Pacientes.nuevoPaciente = 0;
                        
                        
                        
                    }else{
                        cargarTablasPaciente();
                        limpiarCajas();
                        IDultimoPaciente();
                        Pacientes.nombres.requestFocus();
                    }
            } else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al guardar los datos");
            }
            

        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Guardar Paciente "+ex);
        }
    }
```

Mi clase conexión es esta:

```
package Datos;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class ConexionS {
    
   private static Connection con = null;
   public static Connection getConnection(){
      try{
         if( con == null ){
             
            String driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"; 
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://HOST:Port/DatabaseName?useCompresion=true&autoReconnet=true&useSSL=false";
           String usuario = "User";
           String password = "Password";


            
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,password);
            //System.out.println("Conection Succesfull");
         }
     }
     catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error Conexion a la Base de Datos "+ex);
     }
     return con;
   }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido Ranger, recomiendo que adjuntes con el error, el código que has programado para que podamos ayudarte de una manera más sencilla teniendo algo sobre lo que plantear el problema.

Comment: Agregue el código que utilizo para guardar. Pero creo que el problema no es el método que utilizo  para guardar los registro en la Base de Datos porque si utilizo otro hosting que no sea Hostinger me funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Claro, es cosa del hosting. Pero realmente el lío es que tu pool de conexiones no está configurado de forma defensiva para asegurar que las conexiones estén disponibles cuando las vas a usar y que el servidor no las mate antes de tiempo. Es necesario entonces que nos muestres: cómo te conectas a la BD?

Comment: Si, ya lo publique. Si me pudieras explicar lo que dices sobre el pool de conexiones. !!Gracias de antemano